# UIButton as a subview not responding

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uibutton

I have a `UIButton` inside of a `UIView` inside of a `UIImageView` that is not responding to touches. I can't figure out why. I've broken the code down to its simplest form while still doing what my original program does.

```
#import "TestVideoViewController.h"

@interface TestVideoViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic)UIImageView *panel;
@property (strong, nonatomic)UIView *panelSC;
@property (strong, nonatomic)UIButton *panelButtonSC;
@property (strong, nonatomic)UIButton *videoButton;

@end

@implementation TestVideoViewController

-(void) viewDidLoad {

    _panelButtonSC  = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [_panelButtonSC addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressedSC:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [_panelButtonSC setTitle:@"Open" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    _panelButtonSC.frame = CGRectMake(511, 701, 66, 67);

    _panel = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 768, 824, 600)];
    _panel.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    _panelSC = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 784, 560)];
    _panelSC.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    _videoButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [_videoButton addTarget:self action:@selector(playVideo:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [_videoButton setTitle:@"Play" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [_videoButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    _videoButton.frame = CGRectMake(400, 400, 200, 40);

    [_panelSC addSubview:_videoButton];

    [_panel addSubview:_panelSC];

    [self.view addSubview:_panel];
    [self.view addSubview:_panelButtonSC];

}

- (IBAction)buttonPressedSC:(UIButton*)sender {

    [self animatePanelUp];
}

- (IBAction)playVideo:(UIButton*)sender {

    NSLog(@"play video");
}

- (void) animatePanelUp {
    [UIView animateWithDuration: 0.5
                          delay: 0.0
                        options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                     animations:^{
                         _panel.frame = CGRectMake(47, 166, 929, 602);
                     }
                     completion:nil];

}

@end
```

I've looked at every similar answer here. To the best of my knowledge all of my framing is correct. There has got to be something simple and stupid that I'm missing. Why doesn't the "playVideo" method ever fire? The only time it works is if I add the button directly to `self.view`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

UIImageView keeps userInteractionEnabled as false by default - add following line of code it will work.

```
_panel.userInteractionEnabled = true;
```

Comment: So if the superview has user interaction disabled, any subviews of that will be disabled as well?

Comment: I have never run across this before. Thank you! I was having other similar issues in my code and this helped tremendously. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

As you are adding a few subview upon one another, check that your button is clickable and no other subview is eating up the touch event, and overall make sure that your views are user action enabled.

**Hint:**

There might have some problem with the imageview used, as it will have user interaction disabled by default.

Use UIView instead or do this:

```
_panelSC.userInteractionEnabled = true;
```

Comment: Reading your answer again, you had the right idea, but the wrong variable. The image view was _panel not _panelSC. But you were right, it was the problem and needed user interaction enabled. So thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure user interaction is enabled of the parent view. UIImageView by default has userInteractionEnabled false.

```
_panel.userInteractionEnabled = true
```

Comment: Reading your answer again, you had the right idea, but the wrong variable. The image view was _panel not _panelSC. But you were right, it was the problem and needed user interaction enabled. So thank you.